# Placement of dependent clauses in a sentence in scientific writing

Tags: clauses, toponyms

I would like to present the following two variations of the same sentence:

> 1. Thus, alternative treatments have been developed, such as radiation or demineralization, which overcome these shortcomings.

and

> 2. Thus, alternative treatments, such as radiation or demineralization, that overcomes these shortcomings have been developed.

Is there a specific reason why the second variation of the first sentence is incorrect? I suspect that, aside from the erroneous use of *that* vs *which*, the sentence isn't technically incorrect, but merely lacks the flow of the first sentence.

Comment: Thus, alternative treatments have been developed. Radiation, or demineralization, overcomes [these?...refers to what?] shortcomings.

Comment: Or "In order to overcome these shortcomings, alternative treatments such as radiation or demineralization have been developed." That makes *these* a bit less problematic.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence has a simple verbal disagreement:

*Thus, alternative treatments, such as radiation or demineralization, that **overcomes** these shortcomings have been developed*

This sentence uses the singular form of the verb "overcome", but there are multiple treatments, so you need to use the plural form.  The corrected sentence would be:

*Thus, alternative treatments, such as radiation or demineralization, that **overcome** these shortcomings have been developed*

Comment: I'd replace the 'or' with 'and'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's a bit of a puzzle. Since the alternatives are not to each other, it should probably be *and*, but I think our ear is accustomed to hearing *or* with *alternatives*. On the other hand, the *or* makes it clear that *radiation* and *demineralization* are two separate alternatives and not an example of one of the alternative treatments. But I imagine that would be understood by the reader anyway.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — You can't change 'or' to 'and' without changing the scientific meaning, or at least making it ambiguous. 'And' would imply radiation in combination with demineralization, whereas I'm pretty sure these are two separate alternatives.

Comment: @David If you're concerned that context doesn't disambiguate sufficiently, 'Thus, alternative treatments, two examples being radiation and demineralization, ...'. I'm not happy with the 'or' there with a list of examples.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — Agreed. I was writing an answer to the question and found myself writing "and", and without seeing your comment came to the same conclusion. The problem with scientific writing is the amount of information one has to convey. One has to shift around dependent clauses, restructure sentences and make compromises to ensure clarity. The question is naive in terms of one is right and one is wrong (although 2. is horribly clumsy) — one needs the previous sentence and context to advise on relevant alternatives. (Which is why I gave up. Also, to avoid going over the that/which thing.)